# Sketch the region enclosed by the given curves. Decide whether to integrate with respect to x or y. Draw a typical approximating rectangle.

Tags: calculus

The problem is from Calculus II.
And find the area -> 2x + y^2 = 8, x = y based on this information.
So the graph shows that the rectangle lies from x = 0 to x = 4 horizontally.
How do i set up an integral for this? 
I tried to put the integral from 0 to 4 of -y^2/2+4 - y dy
Am i on the right track?

Comment: Very much the right track, but to find the limits of integration, find where the curves meet. Note that some of your region is below the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

We wish to find the area between the curves $2x + y^2 = 8$ and $y = x$.  Substituting $y$ for $x$ in the equation $2x + y^2 = 8$ yields
\begin{align*}
2y + y^2 & = 8\\
y^2 + 2y - 8 & = 0\\
(y + 4)(y - 2) & = 0
\end{align*}
so the line $y = x$ intersects the parabola $2x + y^2 = 8$ at the points $(-4, -4)$ and $(2, 2)$.  Solving the equation $2x + y^2 = 8$ for $x$ yields
$$x = 4 - \frac{1}{2}y^2$$
From sketching the graphs of the parabola and the line, we see that the $x$-values on the parabola are at least those on the line when $-4 \leq y \leq 2$.

[image: area_between_line_and_parabola]

Therefore, the area between the curves is 
\begin{align*}
A & = \int_{-4}^{2} \left(4 - \frac{1}{2}y^2 - y\right) dy\\
  & = \left[4y - \frac{1}{6}y^3 - \frac{1}{2}y^2\right]\Bigg\vert_{-4}^{2}\\
  & = \left(8 - \frac{4}{3} - 2\right) - \left(-16 + \frac{32}{3} - 8\right)\\
  & = 18
\end{align*}
square units.